# Как узнать какая сейчас выставлена настройка --max-old-space-size в node js?

Tags: node.js, v8

Есть приложение nodeJs запущенное на сервере.
Можно ли узнать какой текущий объем максимальной памяти для него доступен?

То есть какое точное значние --max-old-space-size задано.

Версия node 8.

Comment: На сколько знаю - снаружи никак. Если только в приложение встроить [вывод статистики](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processmemoryusage)

Comment: Получается при выводе heapTotal и есть значение заданное max-old-space-size?

Comment: Получается что так.